# How to put DateTimeControl ErrorMessage as '*' during required field validation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calendar, asp.net, validation

There is a DateTimeControl on my WebPage which i is a ReqiredField. I have set the properties of the control as follows

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl runat="server" ID="txtDOB" DateOnly="True" LocaleId="2057" IsRequiredField="true" ErrorMessage="*">
</SharePoint:DateTimeControl>
```

I have set the Error Message to **`*`** but i get the mesage as **`You must specify a value for this required field.`**  instead of **`*`**

Please help me to display ErrorMEssage as * instead of the default long message. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Custom Error Message you use this Code..

```
<sharepoint:datetimecontrol id="dteDemo" runat="server" dateonly="true" />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="valDate" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="dteDemo$dteDemoDate"
            Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ErrorMessage="*">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: `ControlToValidate="dteDemo$dteDemoDate"` how do i set it to my control id `ID="txtDOB"` should it be `ControlToValidate="txtDOB$txtDOBDate"`

Comment: just try and see the result Ishan

Comment: Welll i used required field validator.thank you for the help. can u please explain me what `dteDemo$dteDemoDate` means? What this does? Because in `ControlToValidate` we only specify control ID, without any dollar or anything.